# ColdFusion Facebook Share button with Title using Custom image and description

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

Currently, I use this `anchor` to create a `facebook` share button where I can customize its image, Title and Description.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p
           [url]=#CGI.SERVER_NAME##CGI.PATH_INFO#?#CGI.QUERY_STRING#p
           [images][0]=MySiteImage.jpg&amp;p
           [title]=#PageTitleGoesHere#&amp;p
           [summary]=My Site Facebook Button Sharer">
    <img src="/images/chicklets/FaceBook_Share.png">
</a>
```

How can I get my current Page Title where I can put in the `#PageTitleGoesHere#` value?

Comment: From the same place you define the value of the `<title>` tag?

Comment: Yes. From the same page

Comment: You don't have to repeat the title in the sharing url, facebook will scrape your page and grab it from the title element. You can test it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. Using open graph markup gives you even more control over the metadata used by FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make your current page title a variable and then output it both in your URL and  tags?

```
<cfset pageTitle = "Your title">

<title>#pageTitle#</title>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p
       [url]=#CGI.SERVER_NAME##CGI.PATH_INFO#?#CGI.QUERY_STRING#p
       [images][0]=MySiteImage.jpg&amp;p
       [title]=#pageTitle#&amp;p
       [summary]=My Site Facebook Button Sharer">
<img src="/images/chicklets/FaceBook_Share.png">
</a>
```

Comment: You need to put `<cfoutput>` tags around those variable references.

Comment: I also need to wrap <head></head> around <title> and a lot of other stuff. I was just giving a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have control on setting the page title but you want to call it in other pages where you have control of.

You can get the page title from the page buffer

```
 <cfset pageContent = getPageContext().getOut().getString()>
 <cfset pageTitleStart = FindNoCase("<title>",pageContent) + len("<title>")>
 <cfset pageTitleCount = FindNoCase("</title>",pageContent) - pageTitleStart>
 <cfset pageHeader = MID(pageContent, pageTitleStart, pageTitleCount )>
 <cfoutput>"#pageHeader#"</cfoutput>
```